# Deployment error on JBoss 7.0.2

Tags: jboss7.x, jbpm

I'm trying to deploy my JBpm application on Jboss 7.0.2.

I have defined a persistence unit for both jbpm and my business entities.
I configured the Transaction Manager with Spring 3.1.3.

Everything works well on a Tomcat 7.0, but when I deploy on a Jboss 7.0.2 then I get a javax.persistence.PersistenceException.

To fix the error, I added the following element in my persistence unit:

```
<mapping-file>META-INF/ProcessInstanceInfo.hbm.xml</mapping-file>
```

but then I get another exception refering to my business entities:

```
[...]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class     eu.publications.ceres.persistence.domain.Registration
[...]
```

Do you have an idea why on tomcat everything works fine and on JBoss not?
What does JBoss behind the scene?

Thank you

persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="ceres2013.persistence.unit">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <mapping-file>META-INF/JBPMorm.xml</mapping-file>

    <class>org.drools.persistence.info.SessionInfo</class>
    <class>org.drools.persistence.info.WorkItemInfo</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.process.audit.ProcessInstanceLog</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.process.audit.NodeInstanceLog</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.process.audit.VariableInstanceLog</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="4" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="ceres2013.persistence.unit" />
</bean>
```

StackTrace:

```
[...]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: ceres2013.persistence.unit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
      at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:900) [hibernate-entitymanager-3.5.4-Final.jar:]
      at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:74)     [hibernate-entitymanager-3.5.4-Final.jar:]
      [...]
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: ProcessInstancesWaitingForEvent
      at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:437) [hibernate-core-3.5.4-Final.jar:]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution a few weeks ago. Your comment is right. 
I had to add all my domain entities in the persistence-unit because JBoss does not look for the @Entity annotations (Tomcat does). I ended up with something like:

```
<persistence-unit name="org.jbpm.persistence.jpa" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <mapping-file>META-INF/JBPMorm.xml</mapping-file>
    <mapping-file>META-INF/ProcessInstanceInfo.hbm.xml</mapping-file>

    <class>...</class>
    ...
    <class>...</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="4" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are getting is related with one of your entities, is that mapped in a persistence.xml file?

The error about Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: ProcessInstancesWaitingForEvent

Can be caused because you are mapping the ProcessInstanceInfo class with the wrong mapping for the hibernate version that you are using.

Cheers

PS: by the way, are you testing with 5.4.0.Final?